# Incorrect path for generated coffee sourcemaps when serving with nodejs

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, gruntjs, source-maps

I'm using `coffeescript` to do some work. The `coffeescript` is compiled to `js` with `grunt` and served with a simple `nodejs` express app.

My folder structure does follow the common one with a `assets` folder for things to be compiled (`coffeescript`, `stylus`) and public folder with the compiled stuff (`js`, `css`):

```
/
-- assets /
          -- coffee /
                    -- lib /
                           -- util.coffee
                    -- main.coffee
          -- styl
-- public /
          -- css
          -- js /
                -- lib /
                       -- util.js
                -- main.js
```

My `coffee` setup in `grunt` is:

```
coffee:
  client:
    options:
      sourceMap: true
      #sourceRoot: '??'
    files: [
      expand:   true
      cwd:      'assets/coffee/'
      src:      ['**/*.coffee']
      dest:     'public/js/'
      ext:      '.js'
    ]
```

To serve files from the assets dir I added this to be a static directory in my express app:

```
app.use express.static(process.cwd() + '/assets')
```

Chrome correctly recognizes that the are source maps but the location to the coffee files are wrong. For example a url looks like `http://localhost:3000/assets/coffee/main.coffee`. Of course this results in a 404 because `assets` is the root for all `coffee` files and is served by my express app.

So I need to adjust the `sourceRoot` variable.

- If I set `sourceRoot` to `sourceRoot: '/assets/'`, Chrome generates links to `http://localhost:3000/assets/main.coffee`.
- If I set it to `sourceRoot: '/coffee/'` the link is `http://localhost:3000/coffee/main.coffee`. This works for files in `assets/coffee/`. Files in a subdirectory of `assets/coffee/` like `assets/coffee/lib/` aren't found (the generated link is `http://localhost:3000/coffee/util.coffee`)

Setting the `sourceRoot` option seems to remove the folder structure?!

Long question short: What's the correct setting for `sourceRoot`? How can I preserve the folder structure?

---

I filed this issue as a possible bug report: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/3075

Answer (score 0):

This appears to actually be a bug in the CoffeeScript Grunt task.

See: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee/blob/master/tasks/coffee.js#L87

```
options = _.extend({
    generatedFile: path.basename(paths.dest),
    sourceRoot: mapOptions.sourceRoot,
    sourceFiles: mapOptions.sourceFiles
  }, options);
```

Here, if the options object has a "sourceRoot" element, it will override the generated sourceRoot which is created by this function:

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee/blob/master/tasks/coffee.js#L130

```js
var createOptionsForFile = function (file, paths) {
  return {
    code: grunt.file.read(file),
    sourceFiles: [path.basename(file)],
    sourceRoot: appendTrailingSlash(path.relative(paths.destDir, path.dirname(file)))
  };
};
```

Which uses the relative path from the destination directory to where the source file is (which would probably work if you mapped things like /js to /public/js instead, but for you there will be an extra ../ in the path).

For your case, it might work if you modified the code so that you replaced the `options = _.extend({...` code with something like:

```js
var newRoot = undefined
if (options.sourceRoot) newRoot = appendTrailingSlash(path.join(options.sourceRoot, path.dirname(file)));
options = _.extend({
    generatedFile: path.basename(paths.dest),
    sourceRoot: mapOptions.sourceRoot,
    sourceFiles: mapOptions.sourceFiles
  }, options);
if (newRoot) options.sourceRoot = newRoot;
```

I think that will work because `file` should be relative to your `cwd` setting.

If that change to the Grunt task works, it would be worth making a cleaner version and submitting a pull request, because I think if your .coffee files are in a directory tree, that should be reflected in your sourcemaps' sourceRoot property.